# access validation rules only one space in full name

Tags: validation, ms-access

I used the validation rules "* *" to make sure there is only one single space in the table entry, if error, the error msg window will pop out.

However when 2 spaces are entered, there was no error window at all, which is not what I want.

How I can create a validation rule to ensure only one space in the full name while no space in front & behind the full name?

Thank you for your time in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily prohibit more than one space by using the following rule:

```
Not Like "* * *"
```

If you want to enforce one space, and one space only, you can use:

```
Like "* *" And Not Like "* * *"
```

Comment: Thank you and you are my life saver!